# Can I set env var and use it in the same command line?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I need to run two different regressions requiring 
1. two different values of the same env var;
2. two different .bashrc setups;
3. they cannot run concurrently.
Can I do something like this:

```
% export E=value1 ; cp ~/.bashrc.1 ~/.bashrc ; run1 ; export E=value2 ; cp ~/.bashrc.1 ~/.bashrc ; run2
```

My doubt stems from being unsure whether `export E=value2` will take effect for the environment of `run2`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure then just set it for the executable alone.

```
% cp ~/.bashrc.1 ~/.bashrc ; E=value1 run1 ; cp ~/.bashrc.1 ~/.bashrc ; E=value2 run2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily verify it by yourself:

```
 export E=a; printenv E; export E=b; printenv E
```

outputs

```
a
b
```

A semicolon separates two statements which happen to be written on one line. The export command sets an environment variable, which stays set until its value changes. If you want the value be changed for just one command, don't use export. Example:

```
export E=c; E=d printenv E; printenv E
```

outputs

```
d
c
```